# LTE to WIFI connections not working for WebRTC connection but Wifi to Wifi does

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, webrtc

I’m writing a video chat application and I’m currently using google’s public STUN server and making request to xirsys’ endpoint for remote TURN servers. When I look at the logs I noticed bag tcp packets are being sent with devices using LTE connection and udp packets being sent with devices using WiFi connection. At first, I assumed that the issue was that I was only using STUN servers instead of both TURN and STUN servers. However, I’m still getting “data.sdp is undefined” and/or the icestateconnection is stuck in the state of “checking.” Can someone please not only review and analyze the code and it’s fallacies but explain why this is occurring and provide any resources you know to help my understanding of the issue. Thanks!

[code]

```
//fetch for ice servers
if (servers) {
  console.log(`servers: ${JSON.stringify(servers.v.iceServers, null, 2)}`);
  iceServers = [
    ...servers.v.iceServers,
    {"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
    {"url":'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
    {"url":'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
    {"url":'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
    {"url":'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
  ];
  return;
}

//configuration
pc = new RTCPeerConnection({"iceServers": iceServers};);

//exchange to signaling server
exchange(data) {
const fromId = data.from;

if (!pc)
  this.createPC(fromId, false);

console.log(`Data: ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`);
console.log(`Data.sdp ${data.sdp}`);
if (data.sdp) {
  console.log('exchange sdp', data.sdp);
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp), function () {
    if (pc.remoteDescription.type === "offer")
      pc.createAnswer(function(desc) {
        console.log('createAnswer', desc);
        pc.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
          console.log('setLocalDescription', pc.localDescription);
          socket.emit('exchange', {'to': fromId, 'sdp': pc.localDescription });
        }, logError);
      }, logError);
  }, logError);
} else {
  console.log('exchange candidate', data);
  pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
}
```

}

Comment: On what devices are you getting that error?  Are you able to see any STUN packet transfer with Wireshark or are you testing on mobile devices only?  Can you supply the WebRTC internals dump for these connections?

Comment: @LeeSylvester after hacking at it some more I noticed that the candidate is not being added as an ICE candidate even though 'exchange candidate' is being logged. Is my method incorrect when handling LTE to Wifi connections? Wifi to Wifi is successful with the same method above.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be any different.  Are you checking the value of pc and data.candidate when it fails to assign?  I'm wondering if there's a race condition and the candidate allocation is being skipped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I initiated my configuration for the ICE Servers before my servers were set after a network request! Problem solved!